# Check if value exist in next object in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

first of all thank you for your time to reading this.
My question is how i can check if value exist in the object in foreach loop So far i done this.

SQL query to get messages and value to check a minute difference between each row(to check if user posted messages within a minute so i can display profile image at the end of last message for this group)

```
"SELECT *,id, sentOn, timestampdiff(minute,sentOn,(SELECT sentOn FROM messages t2 WHERE t2.id < t1.id ORDER BY t2.id DESC LIMIT 1)) AS diff FROM messages t1"
```

And simply retrieving messages

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

And display messages

```
foreach ($messages as $user) {
    $next = next($messages);

    echo 'User: '.$user->message.'<br/>'.((@$next->diff != '0') ? 'Profile image. chats ends at SUN 12:20 PM<br/><br/>' : '');
}

Here's result 
Jon: Hi
Jon: hello
Profile image. 
Chats end at SUN 12:20 PM

Jon: hello?
Profile image. 
Chats end at SUN 12:20 PM

Jon: remember me?
Profile image. 
Chats end at SUN 12:20 PM
```

Sorry if this looks confusing, Let me explain so i want to check if the message is the last message from that group (above query) then display profile image at end of message which this method does. But if i remove the @ from $next->diff in the loop it will throw **get property 'diff' of non-object**

Comment: Check if `$next` exists with `empty()`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if `$next` exists. If can be done with `empty` for example:

```
(!empty($next) && $next->diff != '0') 
    ? 'Profile image. chats ends at SUN 12:20 PM<br/><br/>' : ''
```